# C# with MySQL. Get information about cells, rows and its values from MySQL table

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, forms, winforms

I'm making application with C# Windows forms with MySQL and I need advices how should I implement the next:

1. I need to find the biggest and the largest decimal values from the whole column which could contain any amount of values. I need to get them to some sort of array or list (?) and then study them or it is better to make it with MySQL commands?
2. I need to calculate the sum (or do any other math operation) of all decimal values from MySQL column values.

And in general where is the best way to do this operations? on the MySQL side or on the WinForms side?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - as it stands, your question is very broad, and likely to invite answers based on opinion. "In general" means different things to different people...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your business logic and program design, it can be done on either end. in case of MySql a stored procedure can be created that performs the functionality that you require, and that SP can later be called in your code to produce the results. if you wish to do that in your winforms app, I'd prefer to use Entity framework to access the data and then use LINQ to perform the functionality that you require.

Comment: Thanks for this tips. Probably will use them for next projects that would be bigger. Have a nice day, Salman.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `System.Data.MySqlClient` namespace to interact with MySQL databases.

Making the calculations on the database side or not is up to you, just know that if you have a large number of records in the table this will take some time.

What I usually do is a simple `SELECT` and than iterate through the rows on what returns to process the data. You can use the `MySqlDataAdapter` to get a `DataTable` to do so.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using(var dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT decimals FROM myTable", myConnectionString)) {
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt); //fills the datatable
    double allDoubles = 0.0; // stores the sum
```

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using(var dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT SUM(decimals) FROM myTable", connectionString)) {
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt); //fills the datatable
    double myDoubleSum = 0.0; // stores the sum

```
allDoubles = Convert.ToDouble(row[0].ToString());
```

}
    }

As people said in the comments, you can also do it by using the `SUM` function which if indexed, will take none to no time at all to complete.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using(var dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT SUM(decimals) FROM myTable", connectionString)) {
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt); //fills the datatable
    double myDoubleSum = 0.0; // stores the sum

    allDoubles = Convert.ToDouble(row[0].ToString()); 
}
```

Comment: MySQL supports `SUM()`? `SELECT SUM(decimals) FROM myTable` would be the more senseable way of doing it especially if the table has millions or billions of records.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not right. If you have a table with a million rows, this code could run for hours; if you do "select sum(decimals) from myTable", it should return in milliseconds.

Comment: Yes, it will take some time to run if you have a large number of results.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt not to mention the memory usage in the application to store that amount off records and underwater structures to hold that information.  *""select sum(decimals) from myTable", it should return in milliseconds. "* most likely only when indexed.

Comment: I'm usually scared to use SQL functions because I always kill my databases by using them in the ORDER BY statement haha. I edited it with the more sensible way. Thank you all!

Comment: The "sum" bit has little to do with the indexing - if you have to select a range of records based on a "where" clause, the slow bit is in the "where" clause, not the "sum" bit. It will be just as slow retrieving the records one by one as it will be to do the calculation. The only time it makes sense to do the calculation in C# is if native SQL doesn't support your calculation.

Comment: Thanks for answers and comments guys! This is exactly what I expected. Now I know in which situations I should do this operations either on C# or MySQL side.